# Files Sizes in shared folder with permissions

Tags: windows, powershell, fileserver

I have been tasked to export all file sizes individually in all the shared folder exists on a computer except the system shares with ACL and Shared permissions. 
Something like Treesize output with the Shared and ACL permissions.

I have tried the below code but it is not showing what I need in output.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function Get-ShareSize {
    Param(
    [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:computername
    )

Begin{$objFldr = New-Object -com Scripting.FileSystemObject}

Process{
    foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
        Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -ComputerName $Computer -Filter "not name like '%$'" | %{
            $Path = $_.Path -replace 'C:',"\\$Computer\c$"
            $Size = ($objFldr.GetFolder($Path).Size) / 1GB
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $_.Name
            Path = $Path
            Description = $_.Description
            Size = $Size
            }
        }
    }
}
}

Get-ShareSize -ComputerName localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code already looks quite good, but..

The way you use `-Filter` is wrong and also the part where you convert the `$_.Path` into a UNC path is not correct.

Apart from that, there is no need to us a Com object (`Scripting.FileSystemObject`) to get the actual size of the share.

Try this

```
function Get-ShareSize {
    Param(
        [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:computername
    )

    foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
        Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike '*$' } | ForEach-Object {
            # convert the Path into a UNC pathname
            $UncPath = '\\{0}\{1}' -f $Computer, ($_.Path -replace '^([A-Z]):', '$1$')
            # get the folder size
            try {
                $Size = (Get-ChildItem $UncPath -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1GB
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning "Could not get the file size for '$uncPath'"
                $Size = 0
            }
            # output the details
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Name'        = $_.Name
                'LocalPath'   = $_.Path
                'UNCPath'     = $UncPath
                'Description' = $_.Description
                'Size'        = '{0:N2} GB' -f $Size  # format the size to two decimals
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-ShareSize -ComputerName localhost
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Theo.
What I want is file sizes in these shared folders instead of the total size of the folder and the Shared and NTFS folder permissions